# How do I offer JSON as a url with parameters?

Tags: json, web-services

Can someone point me in the right direction or give me some instructions on how I would publish a site that offers JSON? I know this may sound a bit basic. I have some SQL data that I want to convert to JSON and then have other devices request the JSON using a URL I provide.

Comment: You need to create webservice for your site that will work on JSON.
You may create REST API for your site that other devices or application can consume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of options as far as server-side technology, but in the end, you need to accept the parameters, select your data and return content that is application/json.  Since you have a SQL Server back-end, you might look at Microsoft's Web API as the technology to expose your data.

Comment: Thank you. Got some videos on YouTube queued on building services with Web API. Got some learning to do. Thanks again!